# How to convert txt file into 2d array in Java?

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array

This is my first time working with arrays, especially with files in Java, and I had a problem how to output the data from a file to a 2d array.

So here i'm trying to construct a map for the game  with using these data and keep it to 2D array. How to do it?

**My data in the file:**

```
8
2 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

---

**Error that i got:**

File file
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to File

---

```
File file = new File("map1.txt");
        private final char[] allowed = {'0', '1', '2'};
        public List<Position> pPos = new ArrayList<>();
        Map(Scanner scan) throws InvalidMapException {
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            int size = 8;
            boolean isValid = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                strings.add(size);
                for(char ch : allowed) {
                    if(strings.get(strings.size() - 1).charAt(0) == ch) {
                        isValid = true;
                    }
    
                }
            
                if(!isValid) {
                    throw new InvalidMapException("Illegal character");
                }
    
            }
                isValid = false;
                if(strings.size() != size) {
                    throw new InvalidMapException("Map error");
                }
            isValid = false;
            int chCounter = 0;
            int xCounter = 0;
            int yCounter = 0;
            for(String string : strings) {
                for(char ch : strings.toCharArray()) {
                    if(ch == ' ') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(ch == '2') {
                        pPos.add(new Position(xCounter, yCounter));
    
                    }
                    chCounter++;
                    for(char aCh: allowed) {
                        if(ch == allowed) {
                            isValid = true;
                            break; 
                        }
    
                    }
                    if(!isValid) {
                        throw new InvalidMapException("character error");
                    }
                    isValid = false;
                    chCounter++;
    
                }
                if(chCounter != strings.size()) {
                    System.out.println(chCounter + " " + strings.size());
                    throw new InvalidMapException("size error");
                }
                chCounter = 0;
                yCounter++;
                xCounter = 0;
    
            }
            file = new char[strings.size()][strings.size()];
            
            int i = 0; int j = 0;
            for(String string : strings) {
                for(char ch : string.toCharArray()) {
                    if(ch != ' ') {
                        file[i][j] = ch; //Here is the error.
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to keep solution simple and readable, please try this -

```
    File file = new File("map1.txt");
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        int size = Integer.parseInt(line);
        int[][] array = new int[size][size];
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int j = 0;
            String[] lineValues = line.split(" ");
            for (String value : lineValues) {
                array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(value);
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this very complicated.

Read all lines of your file:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
}
catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Then split the lines with
String.split(" "). You will get an array with all numbers per line. Store them in a list.

After that you can create a 2d array out of the items.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Variable file is of type java.io.File.
You are attempting to assign a char array to it which is not possible. You would need to use something like this

```
char[][] charArray = new char[strings.size()][strings.size()];
```

Regardless, I would suggest you to follow the approach suggested by David instead of the complicated code that you have posted.